# Getting the index of a parent element of an event target

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With this code provided:

```
$("#myList").on("click", "span", function (event) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

And HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li>item 0 <span>span 0</span></li>
    <li>item 1 <span>span 1</span></li>
    <li>item 2 <span>span 2</span></li>
    <li>item 3 <span>span 3</span></li>
</ul>
```

If you click on any of the `<span>` elements, "0" will always be alerted. I think this is because there is only one `<span>` within each `<li>`, so it will always be given the index of 0.

What I want it to do, is return the index of the `<span>`'s parent - in this case, it will be the index of the parent `<li>` within `<ul id="myList">`.
For example, clicking on `<span>span 2</span>` will alert "2".

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9naxotz1/)

Comment: Why does this have upvotes? Lol, it's a pretty basic question.  Whatever, not my judgement to make...  *walks off into the shadows*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either use `$(this).parent().index()` or `$(this).closest('li').index()`.

The latter will alert the index of the li even if you decide to put a new element into your spans and bind the event to that.

Answer (score 1):

Do just that:

```
alert($(this).parent().index());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.fn.parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) method:

```js
$("#myList").on("click", "span", function (event) {
    alert($(this).parent().index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myList">
    <li>item 0 <span>span 0</span></li>
    <li>item 1 <span>span 1</span></li>
    <li>item 2 <span>span 2</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9naxotz1/1/)

JS:

```
alert($(this).parent().index());
```

Answer (score 1):

USE `parent()`.

```
console.log($(this).parent().index());
```

Check out the [jQuery DOCS](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/9naxotz1/2/

```
$("#myList").on("click", "span", function (event) {
    alert($(this).parent().index());
});
```